# SQLiteException while inserting values in the database in Android

Tags: android, exception, sqlite

I'm trying to insert various names in the database and they are inserting exception one such name ie; John O' Mahony. The following is my crash logs:

```
Failure 1 (near "' AS '": syntax error) on 0x302f70 when preparing 'INSERT INTO authors(author_name, book_key) SELECT 'John O'Mahony' AS 'author_name', '0mS5s0RHTlodXqwcbbsHm9Q9D4cmuAaevUL_TEdByhjMp8VQvcvxksF2LoNVf3dM' AS 'book_key''.

E/AndroidRuntime(5442): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "' AS '": syntax error: INSERT INTO authors(author_name, book_key) SELECT 'John O'Mahony' AS 'author_name', '0mS5s0RHTlodXqwcbbsHm9Q9D4cmuAaevUL_TEdByhjMp8VQvcvxksF2LoNVf3dM' AS 'book_key'
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at com.example.elib.database.BookUploader.uploadBookAuthors(BookUploader.java:260)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at com.example.elib.database.BookUploader.uploadBook(BookUploader.java:81)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at com.example.elib.activity.LibraryActivity.setData(LibraryActivity.java:671)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at com.example.elib.http.CommonAsyncTask.onPostExecute(CommonAsyncTask.java:198)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at com.example.elib.http.CommonAsyncTask.onPostExecute(CommonAsyncTask.java:1)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-05 12:37:32.262: E/AndroidRuntime(5442):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my create statement:

```
CREATE_ELIB_AUTHORS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
        TABLE_AUTHORS + " (" +
        "author_id integer primary key autoincrement,"+
        "author_name text," +
        "book_key text"+
        " );";
```

Could you please tell me if there is any way to resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to SELECT the author_name, not John O` Mahony.  I think that is the problem.  But for clarification, please add the table structure.

Comment: can you add table structure of both table

Comment: I have added my CREATE statement just now.

Comment: @fix I have checked out that link and did the same but I'm still getting that exception

Answer (score 0):

try

author_name as 'John O'Mahony'.